# Copy row from one sheet to another based on new entry in list

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a workbook for another user and want it as automatic as possible. In sheet 1 user will copy in sales data, containing multiple rows for each product number. The amount of rows will be different each time.
I want to copy one row of each to Sheet 2 where there is a Vlookup to a Pivot.

Clarifying:

Columns A:K have product data. But there are multiple rows of sales data for each product, delivery to different customers. I just want to copy one row each produkt to another sheet.

I can't find the VBA for " for each new number in column F:F do... "

[image]

Comment: Improve your question, it's really hard to understand what you are asking, You want to copy one row of each what? you want to copy just one row of the pasted data? So why you are saying that the pasted data are everytime different if you want to copy just one row?

Anyway the for each in vba work like this

"for each itm in Objects

next itm"

where the Objects can be a collection, an array or a Range of cells.

Comment: Add this detail editing your question then if you add some image of you sheets would be better...

Comment: I am quite new here so I error a bit but learning :) Picture in post.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't have enough info from your question to be able to modify this code at all, but i built a project a week or so ago with a similar issue. here is my code:

```
Dim c As Integer
Dim find As Double
Dim row As Integer
Dim config As Long
Dim configA As Long
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim o As Integer
Dim LastRow As Range


find = Sheets("Packing Slip").Cells(6, "G").Value

Sheets("Shipping Detail").ListObjects("Table_Shipping_Detail_Lookup").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=find
c = 20

For o = 2 To 175


        If Sheets("Shipping Detail").Cells(o, 6) = find Then
            Sheets("Packing Slip").Cells(c, 2) = Sheets("Shipping Detail").Cells(o, 1)
            Sheets("Packing Slip").Cells(c, 3) = Sheets("Shipping Detail").Cells(o, 7)
            Sheets("Packing Slip").Cells(c, 4) = Sheets("Shipping Detail").Cells(o, 8)
            Sheets("Packing Slip").Cells(c, 5) = Sheets("Shipping Detail").Cells(o, 11)

            config = Sheets("Shipping Detail").Cells(o, 1)
            configA = Sheets("Shipping Detail").Cells(o + 1, 1)

            Do While configA - config = 0
                cnt = cnt + 1
                c = c + 1
                Sheets("Packing Slip").Cells(c, 4) = Sheets("Shipping Detail").Cells(o, 5)
                o = o + 1

                If configA - config = 1 Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
                configA = Sheets("Shipping Detail").Cells(o + 1, 1)
            Loop

            c = c + 1
            configA = configA + 1
        End If
Next o

Sheets("Shipping Detail").ListObjects("Table_Shipping_Detail_Lookup").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6
Worksheets("Packing Slip").Activate
```

This first IF statement pulls over the first listing with data that matches the search from the shipping detail.

If the next row of data in the shipping detail has the same order number, then on the next row now in the packing slip only copies the item (which is the product description) from the 5th column of the shipping detail to the 4th column in the packing slip

If the next now has the same order number but is another product, it will pull the product header to be the next now, and its details to follow

if the next row is a new order all together the program stops.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I think I can rewrite this, didn't think about "Do While" here. THNX!